# Remove Buttons Dynamically from table row

Tags: javascript, angular

I am adding the Button to Element as below.

```
(this.sample as any).element.addEventListener("mouseover", function (e) {
      if ((e.target as HTMLElement).classList.contains("e-rowcell")) {
        let ele: Element = e.target as Element;
        let row = parentsUntil(ele, "e-row");
        this.row = row;
        row.lastChild.appendChild(this.button);
        row.lastChild.appendChild(this.button1);
      }
    }.bind(this));
```

I want to remove button on mouse leave
Please let me know how to do it??
see the below screenshot
[image: B]

Please see the below stackblitz link
[Sample Link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hjfcyi?file=main.ts)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove last element you have added on "mouseover" event,
I have added inside load method after mouseover event.

```
 this.gridInstance.element.addEventListener("mouseleave", function(e){
        console.log(this.lastRow.lastChild.lastChild.remove());
      }.bind(this))
```

I have tested it.

Answer (score 0):

You can have buttons in HTML by default and show / hide them in CSS.

```
button {
   display: none;
}
.row:hover button {
   display: block;
}
```

Comment: i want to do it from the component on mouse leave event

Comment: see the above provided stackblitz link